# updpacket.send throws exception

Tags: android, udp

here is my code i dont know why UDP_packet.send(outgoing); throws exception

```
               int SERVERPORT = 9876;
               InetAddress SERVER_IP = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");




                // send UDP packet
                DatagramSocket UDP_packet = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
                UDP_packet.setBroadcast(true);

                String fxx = latcrd.getText().toString();
                String fyy = longcrd.getText().toString();

                String str = fxx + "," + fyy;
                byte[] b = str.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket outgoing = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length,
                        SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
                try{
                UDP_packet.send(outgoing);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

prevoiusly it was ok but now it just stop working and i really dont knw whats the problem

Comment: What exception? Please share your stacktrace.

Comment: this is the exception i got Exception dispatching input event.
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I got the answer of my own question.
Actually I was sending a udp packet on network in main thread and it is not allow to send packet on a network in main thread.
Thanks